# C Simple calculator, getting rid of useless lines

Tags: c

The calculator program was an assignment for my C introduction web class.

How would I better include this section: (currently included in every else if statement)

```
                printf("\nSyötä ensimmäinen luku:");
                scanf("%d", &ekaluku);

                printf("Syötä toinen luku:");
                scanf("%d", &tokaluku);
```

in the code without changing [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZMX0.jpg))?

Source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int laskesumma(int a, int b);
int laskeerotus(int a, int b);
int lasketulo(int a, int b);

int main(void)  
{
    int valinta, ekaluku, tokaluku;

    do {

        printf("1: kahden luvun summa\n2: kahden luvun erotus\n3: kahden luvun tulo\n<0: ohjelman lopetus\n\nValitse laskutoimitus:");
        scanf("%d", &valinta);


        if (valinta < 0)
        { printf("Ohjelma lopetetaan...\n\n"); }

        else if (valinta == 1)
        {  

            printf("\nSyötä ensimmäinen luku:");
            scanf("%d", &ekaluku);

            printf("Syötä toinen luku:");
            scanf("%d", &tokaluku);

            printf("%d + %d = %d\n\n", ekaluku, tokaluku, laskesumma(ekaluku,tokaluku)); 


        }

        else if (valinta == 2)
        { 
            printf("\nSyötä ensimmäinen luku:");
            scanf("%d", &ekaluku);

            printf("Syötä toinen luku:");
            scanf("%d", &tokaluku);

            printf("%d - %d = %d\n\n", ekaluku, tokaluku, laskeerotus(ekaluku,tokaluku)); 

        }

        else if (valinta == 3)
        { 

            printf("\nSyötä ensimmäinen luku:");
            scanf("%d", &ekaluku);

            printf("Syötä toinen luku:");
            scanf("%d", &tokaluku);

            printf("%d * %d = %d\n\n", ekaluku, tokaluku, lasketulo(ekaluku,tokaluku)); 

        }

        else 
        { printf("Antamasi luku ei kelpaa.\n"); }

    } while (valinta>0);

    return 0;
}

//Addition
int laskesumma(int a, int b) {
    int tulos;
    tulos = a+b;
    return tulos;
}

//Subtraction
int laskeerotus(int a, int b) {
    int tulos; 
    tulos = a-b;
    return tulos;
}   

//Multiplication
int lasketulo(int a, int b) {
    int tulos; 
    tulos = a*b;
    return tulos; 
}
```

Is there anything else I could fix for better readability or decreasing the size of the program?

Comment: If your code works, maybe you want to navigate to [codereview.se].

Comment: Since the numerical value input and output patterns are the same, summarize it.

Comment: This would be why you should always write source code in English: you might want to show it to other people. On SO for example.

Comment: yeah, sorry, the web interface and it's compiler only accepts the values requested (finnish), I thought of translating first, but ran out of time and was afraid I wouldn't remember why I wrote the code like I did if I rewrote the post later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you repeat a code block somewhere in your program, you should always consider to put that code block into a function. That will make it much easier to maintain your code.

Besides that I'll suggest that you don't use `scanf` - it has many surprises. For instance try to give your program the input `1a`

Instead use `sscanf` and `fgets` as they'll give you less surprises.

The function could look like:

```
int get_input(FILE *fp, int n)
{
    int d = 0;
    char line[LINESIZE];

    if (n > 0)
    {
        printf("Input the %d. number\n", n);
    }

    if(!fgets(line, LINESIZE,fp))
    {
        printf("Error reading input\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (sscanf(line, "%d", &d) != 1)
    {
        printf("Error reading input\n");
        return 0;
    }

    return d;
}
```

and it can be used like:

```
do 
{
    printf("1: kahden luvun summa\n2: kahden luvun erotus\n3: kahden luvun tulo\n<0: ohjelman lopetus\n\nValitse laskutoimitus:");

    valinta = get_input(stdin, 0);
    if (valinta < 0)
    { 
        printf("Ohjelma lopetetaan...\n\n"); 
    }
    else if (valinta == 1)
    {  
        ekaluku= get_input(stdin, 1);
        tokaluku= get_input(stdin, 2);
        printf("%d + %d = %d\n\n", ekaluku, tokaluku, laskesumma(ekaluku,tokaluku)); 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is:

```
int ekaluku_tokaluku(int *ekaluku, int *tokaluku)
{
    printf("\nSyötä ensimmäinen luku:");
    if (scanf("%d", ekaluku) != 1)
        return EOF;

    printf("Syötä toinen luku:");
    if (scanf("%d", tokaluku) != 1)
        return EOF;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the variables are passed to the function as pointers, so there is no `&` in the `scanf()` calls.  Some people might use a prefix such as `p_ekaluku` (or `pEkaluku`) on the names to indicate that they're a pointer.

You'd use it like this:

```
else if (valinta == 1)
{  
    if (ekaluku_tokaluku(&ekaluku, &tokaluku) != 0)
        break;
    printf("%d + %d = %d\n\n", ekaluku, tokaluku, laskesumma(ekaluku, tokaluku));
}
```

Returning 0 on success is a common pattern.  It's always worth checking that your code handles EOF conditions.  You could consider adding `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf()` and before the `scanf()` statements in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a function if you're repeating those lines of codes a lot and return the integer value.

```
int userInput() {
    int ekaluku;
    printf("\nSyötä ensimmäinen luku:");
    scanf("%d", &ekaluku);
    return ekaluki;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be a little bit shorter (number of lines):

```
  int laskesumma(int a, int b) { return (a+b);} //Addition
  int laskeerotus(int a, int b){ return (a-b);} //Subtraction
  int lasketulo(int a, int b) {  return (a*b);} //Multiplication
```

but lower readibility in case of needed more complicated functions...

Answer (score 0):

reduce code like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define make_func(name, op)\
static inline int name(int a, int b){\
    return a op b;\
}\
/**/

make_func(laskesumma , +) //Addition
make_func(laskeerotus, -) //Subtraction
make_func(lasketulo  , *) //Multiplication

#define op(no)   ( " +-*"[no] )
typedef int (*Func)(int,int);
#define func(no) ( (Func[]){ 0, laskesumma, laskeerotus, lasketulo}[no] )

enum { QUIT, ADD, SUB, MUL };

int main(void){
    int valinta, ekaluku, tokaluku;

    do {
        printf("%d: kahden luvun summa\n"
               "%d: kahden luvun erotus\n"
               "%d: kahden luvun tulo\n"
               "<%d: ohjelman lopetus\n\n"
               "Valitse laskutoimitus:", ADD, SUB, MUL, QUIT);fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%d", &valinta);

        switch(valinta){
        case ADD:
        case SUB:
        case MUL:
            printf("\nSyota ensimmainen luku:");fflush(stdout);
            scanf("%d", &ekaluku);

            printf("Syota toinen luku:");fflush(stdout);
            scanf("%d", &tokaluku);

            printf("%d %c %d = %d\n\n", ekaluku, op(valinta), tokaluku, func(valinta)(ekaluku, tokaluku));
            break;
        default:
            if(valinta < QUIT){
                printf("Ohjelma lopetetaan...\n\n");
                return 0;
            }
            printf("Antamasi luku ei kelpaa.\n"); 
        }
    } while (valinta > QUIT);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use switch case in your code

```
do
{
if(valinta<0)
   printf("Ohjelma lopetetaan...\n\n");
switch(valinta)
{
case 1:
case 2:
case 3:
          printf("\nSyötä ensimmäinen luku:");
            scanf("%d", &ekaluku);
            printf("Syötä toinen luku:");
            scanf("%d", &tokaluku);
            break;
default: printf("Antamasi luku ei kelpaa.\n");
}
}while(valinta>0);
```